# How to achieve all elements swapped in an array

Tags: ruby

I have an ordered array which contain 1 to 1000000 elements.
I want to achieve an array such that the elements in the array are swapped with its next element.For instance if we assume the array elements are

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to return an array with elements as

```
 [2,1,4,3,6,5]
```

How do I achieve this in ruby for 100000 such elements? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far. SO it's not code-writing resource.

Comment: What happens if the number of elements is an odd number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a.each_slice(2).map{|inner_a| inner_a.reverse}.flatten
# => [2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5]
```

Description:

`a.each_slice(2)`returns an enumerator (`#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:each_slice(2)>`) with two element couples from your array. To see try `a.each_slice(2).to_a`. This returns `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` with I only have to flatten for your expected result.

See also the first comment if you prefer a shorter notation of it.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(2).map(&:reverse).flatten` short version, more `[1,2,3,4,5,6].each_slice(2).flat_map(&:reverse)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use a minimum amount of memory (since you chose a large array), and assuming the result is to be a mutated array (i.e. not a new array, but a change to the existing array) and finally assuming `a` is always an even number of elements...

```
a.each_index{|x| a[x], a[x+1] = a[x+1], a[x] if x.even?}
```

Possibly more performant...

```
(0...a.size).step(2) {|x| a[x], a[x+1] = a[x+1], a[x]}
```

Comment: You can do `a.each_index{...}`.

Comment: You could also use `(0...a.size).step(2) { ... }` to avoid the conditional.

Comment: Thanks, @stefan, good thought.  I like sawa's suggestion of each_index but the `step(2)` that you suggest sounds performant.  I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
arr = (1..100000).to_a
arr.each_with_index.each_slice(2){|(_,i), (_,j)| arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]}
```

Comment: What is the point of iterating over the elements themselves (what are `a` and `b` for)?

Comment: `a` and `b` is value of array. So in this case we no need them.